# how to submit the form in jquery to server side by escaping or bypassing the Validations that were set

Tags: jquery

how to submit the form in jquery to server side by escaping or bypassing the Validations that were set

Answer (score 1):

You can just call the [DOM (not jQuery) `form.submit()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.submit), like this:

```
$("form")[0].submit();
```

Or if it's by ID:

```
document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
//or
$("#myForm").get(0).submit();
```

This bypasses the jQuery event handlers and prevents them from running, instead it directly submits the `<form>`.